# Python Apache Beam TaggedOutput Not Working

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I'm having an issue with `TaggedOutput`s in Apache Beam (`DataflowRunner`) using Python 3.9.  I've included the necessary pieces of code below for understanding.

Basically the tagged output from `parent_check_pipeline` for `Tag.REQS_SATISFIED`) is not working.  When the code in `CheckParentRequirements` yields that tagged output, the pipeline, basically, ends. I get the correct log that the "Element ... has no parents", but the pipeline stops there and doesn't proceed to "Write to Pubsub Topics."  I think my meaning can be seen in the dataflow graph I included below as well.

The pipeline definitions for each step are separated into functions for ease of testing.  We've used this approach in other beam pipelines and it is working so I'm not sure what's missing here.

Thanks in advance!

#### Other approaches

I've tried declaring the inputs to "Write to Pubsub" as a tuple:

```py
p_publish_messages = (
    (p_check_parents_needed[Tag.REQS_SATISFIED], p_check_parents_exist[Tag.REQS_SATISFIED])
    | "Write to Pubsub Topics" >> beam.ParDo(WriteToPubsubMultiple(topic_1, topic_2))
)
```

which gives the following error:

```
  File ".../lib/python3.9/site-packages/apache_beam/transforms/core.py", line 1578, in expand
    is_bounded = pcoll.is_bounded
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'is_bounded'
```

When using the code defined in `publish_messages_pipeline` with:

```py
p_publish_messages = publish_messages_pipeline([p_check_parents_needed, p_check_parents_exist], pipeline_params)
```

I receive:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/jimmy.hartman/projects/apiary/ces-ingest-eventing/src/dataflow/parent_check_pipeline.py", line 362, in <module>
    run(
  File "/Users/jimmy.hartman/projects/apiary/ces-ingest-eventing/src/dataflow/parent_check_pipeline.py", line 317, in run
    p_publish_messages = publish_messages_pipeline([p_check_parents_needed, p_check_parents_exist], pipeline_params)
  File "/Users/jimmy.hartman/projects/apiary/ces-ingest-eventing/src/dataflow/parent_check_pipeline.py", line 206, in publish_messages_pipeline
    tagged_sources
  File "/Users/jimmy.hartman/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/up-ces-ingest-eventing-qyT-FGDE-py3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/apache_beam/transforms/ptransform.py", line 1095, in __ror__
    return self.transform.__ror__(pvalueish, self.label)
  File "/Users/jimmy.hartman/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/up-ces-ingest-eventing-qyT-FGDE-py3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/apache_beam/transforms/ptransform.py", line 622, in __ror__
    p.run().wait_until_finish()
  File "/Users/jimmy.hartman/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/up-ces-ingest-eventing-qyT-FGDE-py3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/apache_beam/pipeline.py", line 574, in run
    return self.runner.run_pipeline(self, self._options)
  File "/Users/jimmy.hartman/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/up-ces-ingest-eventing-qyT-FGDE-py3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/direct/direct_runner.py", line 131, in run_pipeline
    return runner.run_pipeline(pipeline, options)
  File "/Users/jimmy.hartman/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/up-ces-ingest-eventing-qyT-FGDE-py3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/portability/fn_api_runner/fn_runner.py", line 199, in run_pipeline
    self._latest_run_result = self.run_via_runner_api(
  File "/Users/jimmy.hartman/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/up-ces-ingest-eventing-qyT-FGDE-py3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/portability/fn_api_runner/fn_runner.py", line 212, in run_via_runner_api
    return self.run_stages(stage_context, stages)
  File "/Users/jimmy.hartman/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/up-ces-ingest-eventing-qyT-FGDE-py3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/portability/fn_api_runner/fn_runner.py", line 442, in run_stages
    bundle_results = self._execute_bundle(
  File "/Users/jimmy.hartman/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/up-ces-ingest-eventing-qyT-FGDE-py3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/portability/fn_api_runner/fn_runner.py", line 770, in _execute_bundle
    self._run_bundle(
  File "/Users/jimmy.hartman/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/up-ces-ingest-eventing-qyT-FGDE-py3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/portability/fn_api_runner/fn_runner.py", line 999, in _run_bundle
    result, splits = bundle_manager.process_bundle(
  File "/Users/jimmy.hartman/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/up-ces-ingest-eventing-qyT-FGDE-py3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/portability/fn_api_runner/fn_runner.py", line 1309, in process_bundle
    result_future = self._worker_handler.control_conn.push(process_bundle_req)
  File "/Users/jimmy.hartman/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/up-ces-ingest-eventing-qyT-FGDE-py3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/portability/fn_api_runner/worker_handlers.py", line 380, in push
    response = self.worker.do_instruction(request)
  File "/Users/jimmy.hartman/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/up-ces-ingest-eventing-qyT-FGDE-py3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/sdk_worker.py", line 597, in do_instruction
    return getattr(self, request_type)(
  File "/Users/jimmy.hartman/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/up-ces-ingest-eventing-qyT-FGDE-py3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/sdk_worker.py", line 635, in process_bundle
    bundle_processor.process_bundle(instruction_id))
  File "/Users/jimmy.hartman/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/up-ces-ingest-eventing-qyT-FGDE-py3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/bundle_processor.py", line 1003, in process_bundle
    input_op_by_transform_id[element.transform_id].process_encoded(
  File "/Users/jimmy.hartman/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/up-ces-ingest-eventing-qyT-FGDE-py3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/bundle_processor.py", line 227, in process_encoded
    self.output(decoded_value)
  File "/Users/jimmy.hartman/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/up-ces-ingest-eventing-qyT-FGDE-py3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 528, in output
    _cast_to_receiver(self.receivers[output_index]).receive(windowed_value)
  File "/Users/jimmy.hartman/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/up-ces-ingest-eventing-qyT-FGDE-py3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 240, in receive
    self.consumer.process(windowed_value)
  File "/Users/jimmy.hartman/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/up-ces-ingest-eventing-qyT-FGDE-py3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 908, in process
    delayed_applications = self.dofn_runner.process(o)
  File "/Users/jimmy.hartman/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/up-ces-ingest-eventing-qyT-FGDE-py3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 1419, in process
    self._reraise_augmented(exn)
  File "/Users/jimmy.hartman/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/up-ces-ingest-eventing-qyT-FGDE-py3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 1491, in _reraise_augmented
    raise exn
  File "/Users/jimmy.hartman/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/up-ces-ingest-eventing-qyT-FGDE-py3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 1417, in process
    return self.do_fn_invoker.invoke_process(windowed_value)
  File "/Users/jimmy.hartman/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/up-ces-ingest-eventing-qyT-FGDE-py3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 623, in invoke_process
    self.output_handler.handle_process_outputs(
  File "/Users/jimmy.hartman/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/up-ces-ingest-eventing-qyT-FGDE-py3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 1581, in handle_process_outputs
    self._write_value_to_tag(tag, windowed_value, watermark_estimator)
  File "/Users/jimmy.hartman/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/up-ces-ingest-eventing-qyT-FGDE-py3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 1694, in _write_value_to_tag
    self.main_receivers.receive(windowed_value)
  File "/Users/jimmy.hartman/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/up-ces-ingest-eventing-qyT-FGDE-py3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 240, in receive
    self.consumer.process(windowed_value)
  File "/Users/jimmy.hartman/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/up-ces-ingest-eventing-qyT-FGDE-py3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 908, in process
    delayed_applications = self.dofn_runner.process(o)
  File "/Users/jimmy.hartman/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/up-ces-ingest-eventing-qyT-FGDE-py3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 1419, in process
    self._reraise_augmented(exn)
  File "/Users/jimmy.hartman/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/up-ces-ingest-eventing-qyT-FGDE-py3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 1491, in _reraise_augmented
    raise exn
  File "/Users/jimmy.hartman/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/up-ces-ingest-eventing-qyT-FGDE-py3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 1417, in process
    return self.do_fn_invoker.invoke_process(windowed_value)
  File "/Users/jimmy.hartman/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/up-ces-ingest-eventing-qyT-FGDE-py3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 623, in invoke_process
    self.output_handler.handle_process_outputs(
  File "/Users/jimmy.hartman/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/up-ces-ingest-eventing-qyT-FGDE-py3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 1581, in handle_process_outputs
    self._write_value_to_tag(tag, windowed_value, watermark_estimator)
  File "/Users/jimmy.hartman/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/up-ces-ingest-eventing-qyT-FGDE-py3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 1694, in _write_value_to_tag
    self.main_receivers.receive(windowed_value)
  File "/Users/jimmy.hartman/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/up-ces-ingest-eventing-qyT-FGDE-py3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 240, in receive
    self.consumer.process(windowed_value)
  File "/Users/jimmy.hartman/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/up-ces-ingest-eventing-qyT-FGDE-py3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 908, in process
    delayed_applications = self.dofn_runner.process(o)
  File "/Users/jimmy.hartman/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/up-ces-ingest-eventing-qyT-FGDE-py3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 1419, in process
    self._reraise_augmented(exn)
  File "/Users/jimmy.hartman/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/up-ces-ingest-eventing-qyT-FGDE-py3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 1507, in _reraise_augmented
    raise new_exn.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/Users/jimmy.hartman/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/up-ces-ingest-eventing-qyT-FGDE-py3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 1417, in process
    return self.do_fn_invoker.invoke_process(windowed_value)
  File "/Users/jimmy.hartman/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/up-ces-ingest-eventing-qyT-FGDE-py3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 623, in invoke_process
    self.output_handler.handle_process_outputs(
  File "/Users/jimmy.hartman/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/up-ces-ingest-eventing-qyT-FGDE-py3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 1571, in handle_process_outputs
    for result in results:
  File "/Users/jimmy.hartman/projects/apiary/ces-ingest-eventing/src/dataflow/parent_check_pipeline.py", line 159, in process
    enc_element = json.dumps(element).encode("utf-8")
  File "/Users/jimmy.hartman/.pyenv/versions/3.9.13/lib/python3.9/json/__init__.py", line 231, in dumps
    return _default_encoder.encode(obj)
  File "/Users/jimmy.hartman/.pyenv/versions/3.9.13/lib/python3.9/json/encoder.py", line 199, in encode
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
  File "/Users/jimmy.hartman/.pyenv/versions/3.9.13/lib/python3.9/json/encoder.py", line 257, in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)
  File "/Users/jimmy.hartman/.pyenv/versions/3.9.13/lib/python3.9/json/encoder.py", line 179, in default
    raise TypeError(f'Object of type {o.__class__.__name__} '
TypeError: Object of type _InvalidUnpickledPCollection is not JSON serializable [while running 'Write to Pubsub Topics']
```

#### Code

```py
class CheckParentRequirements(DoFn):
    def process(self, element, *args, **kwargs):
        parents = get_parents(element)
        if parents:
            logging.getLogger(__name__).warning(f"Element {element} has parents: '{parents}'")
            yield TaggedOutput(value=element, tag=Tag.PARENTS_NEEDED)
        else:
            logging.getLogger(__name__).warning(f"Element {element} has no parents")
            yield TaggedOutput(value=element, tag=Tag.REQS_SATISFIED)

class LookupParents(DoFn):
    def process(self, element):
        missing_parents = self.get_missing_entities(parent_id_map, element)
        if missing_parents:
            self.logger.info(f"'{element}' missing parents {missing_parents}.")
            element.update({Key.MISSING_PARENTS: missing_parents})
            yield TaggedOutput(value=element, tag=Tag.MISSING_PARENTS)
        else:
            self.logger.info(f"'{element}' parents found.")
            yield TaggedOutput(value=element, tag=Tag.REQS_SATISFIED)
    
    def get_missing_parents(element):
        ...

class WriteToPubsubMultiple(DoFn):
    def __init__(self, topic_1, topic_2):
        self.topic_1 = topic_1
        self.topic_2 = topic_2
        self.publisher = None

    def setup(self):
        self.publisher = pubsub_v1.PublisherClient()

    def process(self, element, *args, **kwargs):
        logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
        enc_element = json.dumps(element).encode("utf-8")

        self.publisher.publish(self.topic_1, enc_element)
        self.publisher.publish(self.topic_2, enc_element)
        logger.info("Sent message messages.")

        yield None

def parent_check_pipeline(source) -> DoOutputsTuple:
    p_parent_check = (
        source
        | "Check Parent Requirement"
        >> beam.ParDo(CheckParentRequirements()).with_outputs(Tag.PARENTS_NEEDED, Tag.REQS_SATISFIED)
    )
    return p_parent_check


def lookup_parents_pipeline(source: DoOutputsTuple, params: PipelineParams) -> DoOutputsTuple:
    p_parents_exist = source[Tag.PARENTS_NEEDED] | "Lookup Parents" >> beam.ParDo(
        LookupParents(params.database_instance_id, params.database_id)
    ).with_outputs(Tag.MISSING_PARENTS, Tag.REQS_SATISFIED)
    return p_parents_exist


def waiting_room_insert_pipeline(source: DoOutputsTuple, params: PipelineParams):
    p_waiting_room_rows = (
        source[Tag.MISSING_PARENTS]
        | "Create Bigtable Rows" >> beam.ParDo(CreateWaitingRoomRows())
        | "Bigtable Window"
        >> beam.WindowInto(
            window.GlobalWindows(),
            trigger=Repeatedly(AfterAny(AfterCount(100), AfterProcessingTime(10))),
            accumulation_mode=AccumulationMode.DISCARDING,
        )
        | "Write to Bigtable"
        >> WriteToBigTable(params.project_id, params.instance, params.table)
    )
    return p_waiting_room_rows

# Not using this right now as I was troubleshooting. This is now in the `run()` method.
def publish_messages_pipeline(sources: List[DoOutputsTuple], params: PipelineParams):
    tagged_sources = (source[Tag.REQS_SATISFIED] for source in sources)
    p_publish_messages = (
        tagged_sources
        | "Write to Pubsub Topics"
        >> beam.ParDo(WriteToPubsubMultiple(params.topic_1, params.topic_2))
    )
    return p_publish_messages

def run(
    pipeline_options,
    pipeline_params
):
    with Pipeline(options=pipeline_options) as pipeline:
        p_source = (
            pipeline
            | "Read from Pub/Sub" >> io.ReadFromPubSub(subscription=input_subscription)
            | "Parse JSON" >> beam.Map(json.loads)
        )

        p_check_parents_needed = parent_check_pipeline(p_source)

        p_check_parents_exist = lookup_parents_pipeline(p_check_parents_needed, pipeline_params)

        p_waiting_room_insert = waiting_room_insert_pipeline(p_check_parents_exist, pipeline_params)

        p_publish_messages = (
            p_check_parents_needed[Tag.REQS_SATISFIED], p_check_parents_exist[Tag.REQS_SATISFIED]
            | "Write to Pubsub Topics" >> beam.ParDo(WriteToPubsubMultiple(topic_1, topic_2))
        )
```

#### Dataflow graph:

[image]

Comment: Also, I've read that the tagged outputs are called "side outputs", but what to you call a "tagged input" `source["my_tag"]` to another `PTransform`?  I've seen the term "side input" used in a different manner, so I'd like to make sure I'm using correct terminology.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I needed to take advantage of the [apache_beam.Flatten()](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#flatten) transform:

> Flatten is a Beam transform for PCollection objects that store the same data type. Flatten merges multiple PCollection objects into a single logical PCollection.

The new `publish_messages_pipeline` definition would look like this:

```py
def publish_messages_pipeline(sources: List[DoOutputsTuple], params: PipelineParams):
    tagged_sources = (source[Tag.REQS_SATISFIED] for source in sources)
    p_publish_messages = (
        tagged_sources
        | "Flatten inputs" >> beam.Flatten()
        | "Write to Pubsub Topics"
        >> beam.ParDo(WriteToPubsubMultipleFn(params.topic_1, params.topic_2))
    )
    return p_publish_messages
```

Taking the suggestion from @CaptainNabla, I put the "composite transform" code for inserting into bigtable into a class extending `PTransform`.  This not only organizes the code, but allows the graph in Dataflow to be expanded/collapsed for inspection.

```py
class InsertIntoWaitingRoom(PTransform):
    def __init__(self, params: PipelineParams):
        super(InsertIntoWaitingRoom, self).__init__()
        self.params = params

    def expand(self, source: InputT) -> OutputT:
        return (
            source
            | "Create Bigtable Rows" >> beam.ParDo(CreateWaitingRoomRowsFn())
            | "Bigtable Window"
            >> beam.WindowInto(
                window.GlobalWindows(),
                trigger=Repeatedly(AfterAny(AfterCount(100), AfterProcessingTime(10))),
                accumulation_mode=AccumulationMode.DISCARDING,
            )
            | "Write to Bigtable"
            >> WriteToBigTable(
                self.params.project, self.params.instance, self.params.table
            )
        )
```

| collapsed | expanded |
| --- | --- |
| [image] | [image] |

Answer (score 1):

At a first glance, I see nothing wrong with your tagged outputs (assuming `Tag.WHATEVER` returns a string). However, I am a bit confused about the way you outsource pipeline parts. Usually, you would use `PTransform`s instead of simple python functions. That might be the source of your strange behavior.

I would recommend rewriting all your pipeline methods to [PTransforms](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#composite-transform-creation), e.g.

```
class ParentCheckPipeline(beam.PTransform):
    def expand(self, source):
        p_parent_check = (
            source
            | "Check Parent Requirement" >> beam.ParDo(CheckParentRequirements())
            .with_outputs(Tag.PARENTS_NEEDED, Tag.REQS_SATISFIED)
        )
        return p_parent_check
```

Note the mandatory `expand` method, containing your pipeline part.

Comment: You can also use the [annotation `ptransform_fn` to use a function](https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.7.0/apache_beam.transforms.ptransform.html#apache_beam.transforms.ptransform.ptransform_fn) instead of having to create a custom class.

Comment: @CaptainNabla - While not the solution (see below), I did take advantage of this in one area, so thank you!  This also consolidates the composite code for testing purposes.  The `PTransform`s aren't really necessary for my simple  "Map"-style `ParDo` transforms, so I've just moved them into my main "run" method as they are easy enough to test on their own.